# opt premission error

Tags: permissions, sudo, git, opt

am using `Ubuntu Server 20.04` and I'm having permission issue while running a script.

Steps taken:

```
cd /opt/
sudo git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap.git A
sudo ln -s /opt/A/sqlmap.py /usr/bin/1
```

Issue:

```
1 --update
```

Output:

```
[22:31:53] [ERROR] update could not be completed ('fatal Unable to create opt A git index lock Permission denied')
```

[image]

How can i fix that without running `sudo 1 --update` each time ? do i need to change location or anything else?

**UPDATE**:

I've used the following to fix the issue but i would like to confirm if that's the correct approach.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /opt/A
```

Thanks in advance.

Waiting for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the permissions to `/opt` then making sure that `A` and all of its contents are owned by you.

```
sudo chmod 775 /opt
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /opt/A
```